# Create a new variable using dplyr::mutate and pasting two existing variables for user-defined function

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I would like to create a function to join the lower and higher bound of confidence intervals (named as `CIlow` and `CIhigh`) from a data frame. See the data frame below as example.

```
dataframe<-data.frame(CIlow_a=c(1.1,1.2),CIlow_b=c(2.1,2.2),CIlow_c=c(3.1,3.2),
                      CIhigh_a=c(1.3,1.4),CIhigh_b=c(2.3,2.4),CIhigh_c=c(3.3,3.4))
```

The data frame has `CIlow` and `CIhigh` for a number of groups (named as `a`, `b` and `c`) and for a number of variables (in this case two, the rows of the data frame).

```
group<-c("a","b","c")
```

To build my own function I tried the following code:

```
f<-function(df,gr){

enquo_df<-enquo(df)
enquo_gr<-enquo(gr)

r<-df%>%
   dplyr::mutate(UQ(paste("CI",enquo_gr,sep="_")):=
                   sprintf("(%s,%s)",
                           paste("CIlow",quo_name(enquo_gr),sep="_"),
                           paste("CIhigh",quo_name(enquo_gr),sep="_")))

return(r)
}
```

However when using the function

```
library(dplyr)

group<-c("a","b","c")
    dataframe<-data.frame(CIlow_a=c(1.1,1.2),CIlow_b=c(2.1,2.2),CIlow_c=c(3.1,3.2),CIhigh_a=c(1.3,1.4),CIhigh_b=c(2.3,2.4),CIhigh_c=c(3.3,3.4))

f(df=dataframe,gr=group)
```

I do not get the expected output

```
output<-data.frame(CI_a=c("(1.1,1.3)","(1.2,1.4)"),
                  CI_b=c("(2.1,2.3)","(2.2,2.4)"),
                  CI_c=c("(3.1,3.3)","(3.2,3.4)"))
```

but the following error message:

> Error: LHS must be a name or string

Do you know why? How could I solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `enquo_shortgr`?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example (i.e. provide all the data and libraries you are using plus the code)?

Comment: Sorry @F.Privé, the `enquo_shortgr` was a mistake when transfering the code from the real case to this example. The right name is of course `enquo_gr`. I just corrected the code in my question.

Comment: @dvarelas the only package used here is `dplyr` (as written before the only used function, i.e. dplyr::mutate). Anyway, just to clarify I have added the following line in the code of my question: `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Can you provide the expected output? I don't get what your function should return.

Comment: @F.Privé I just added the expected output to my question. Thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

Old school solution:

```
res <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA_character_, nrow(dataframe), ncol(dataframe) / 2))
for (i in seq_along(group)) {
  var <- paste0("CI", c("low", "high"), "_", group[[i]])
  res[[i]] <- sprintf("(%s,%s)", dataframe[[var[[1]]]], dataframe[[var[[2]]]])
}
names(res) <- paste0("CI_", group)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I would prefer a function following the approach of my question.